# How to replace plus(+) sign with a <span>+</span> tag outside singles and double quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a syntax highlight, with live code editor.[image: here the example image]

here de example of string code:

// before.

```
var x = 'person + arthur' + "family + all";
```

// after.

```
var x = 'person + arthur' <span style="color:red;">+</span> "family + all";
```

Im using:

```
var x = string.replace(/\+/g,'<span style="color: red;">+</span>'); // but this replace all.
```

I need replace only outside of single quotes and double quotes.

Im using a Get .innerText, for avoid conflicts in the regex.

Comment: Why outside quotes?

Comment: because inside is a string, string use specific <span> color.

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that `'person + arthur' + "family + all"` results in `"person + arthurfamily + all"`, don't you?

Comment: yes but this is not a live code, this is a string, im making a javascript editor. :D

Comment: this is a string in text contenteditable ('person + arthur' + "family + all"), :D

Comment: not is the live code, the live code is var x = string.replace(/\+/g,'<span style="color: red;">+</span>');

Comment: Regular expressions are [*notoriously bad for parsing HTML*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), since HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: Thanks, What dou you recommend?

Comment: Try out [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/).

Comment: Thanks already used that, but codemirror not replace plus sign. but thanks a lot!

Comment: And codemirror make unnecessary space tabs, and have some errors on save the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
str = `var x = 'person + arthur' + "family + all";`;

str = str.replace(/(['"])[^'"]*\1|[-*\/%+]/g, x => (x.length == 1) ? '<span style="color:red;">' + x + '</span>' : x);


console.log(str)
```

Try it live on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qiUDIy/1).

Basically the regex matches all strings, leaving the characters `[-*\/%+]` which are not inside quotes free to match.